# Showing two markers on map with route between them, How to highlight universities near routing area?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am showing two markers on Google map with route between them. Now I have to highlight universities near routing. I am using following code snippet for map functionality. Please suggest me changes for highlighting universities near that routing area??

Some part of my coding:

```
<?php
    ..........
    ..........
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { //alert(i);
              if(markers[i].length>0)
              {
                var iconBase = "<?php echo BASE_IMAGE;?>pointericon1.png";

                if(markers[i][5]=='1'){

                    var cur_sym=currency_symbols['INR'];
                }else{

                     var cur_sym=currency_symbols['GBP'];
                }
                //alert(markers[i][2]);
                //alert(markers[i][3]);


                var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][2], markers[i][3]);
                bounds.extend(position);

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: position,
                    map: map,
                    title: markers[i][0]+','+markers[i][1],
                    icon: iconBase,
                    label: cur_sym+markers[i][4]
                });

                // Allow each marker to have an info window
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                    return function () {
                        infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));

                // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
              }   
            }
           .......................
           .......................
?>
```

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what data you have and what you want to display?  Its not clear what this code relates to or which data relates to the markers you want to display

Comment: this is just main part of my code.. i am showing multiple markers on map.. & now just want to highlight universities in visible part of map

Comment: Are the universities part of your pointers? If yes, then you can use a different icon to display the universities.

Comment: no i've to highlight universities near markers

Answer (score 0):

If you know the universities near markers use gif image instead of normal marker. Gif marker code like that as

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: position,
          map:map,
          title: markers[i][0]+','+markers[i][1],
          icon:iconBase,
          optimized:false
 });
```

Comment: Using backend technology or google map distance service